# how to show/display the acquired data from database using snapshot/querysnapshot in my designed html page?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I tried `.innerhtml` way but do not know why it isn't displaying anything just a blank page.

When i use `snapshot` instead of `querysnapshot` it works but shows different (last doc entered) instead of searched one.

**Function Code**

```
function renderHTML(doc){
  // TODO: do something with the data 

  // To create elements (such as list or span) 
  var plano = document.createElement('span');
  plano.innerHTML = doc.data().plate;
  // list.appendChild(plano);

  // To append the the list to querySelector
  document.getElementsByClassName(".numPlate").appendChild(plano);
 }
function ser(){
  n=0;
  var num = document.getElementById("plateNo").value;
  if(num == ""){
    var ent = document.getElementById("plateNo");
    ent.classList.add("invalid");
    document.getElementById("err").setAttribute("data-error", "Wrong");
  }
  else{
    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
        var ans = num.localeCompare(plates[i]); 
        if(ans==0){
          db.collection("details").where('plate', '==', num).get()
            .then(snapshot => {
               if (snapshot.empty) {
                 console.log('No matching documents.');
               return;
                }  
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
          renderHTML(doc);
          });
        })
           .catch(err => {
           console.log('Error getting documents', err);
        });
           n=1;
           window.open("/pages/detail.html","_self");
           break;
        }}
        if(n==0) {
          var element = document.getElementById("plateNo");
          element.classList.add("invalid");
          document.getElementById("err").setAttribute("data-error", "Invalid Entry");
        }
  }}
```

**HTML Code for input Page**

```
<form id="platef" action="/" method="get" target="_self" name="serf" class="col s12 l12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s7 l3 offset-s2 offset-l4 asd">
                <i class="material-icons prefix" id="ic" style="top: 12px;" onclick="ser()" required>search</i>
                <input id="plateNo" class="validate" type="text" name="no" style="text-transform:uppercase" onsubmit="ser()" required>
                <label for="plateNo">Number plate</label>
                <span class="helper-text" data-error="Invalid Entry" id="err"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
```

**HTML CODE of Display Page**

```
<div id="details" class="details container">
<div class="row">
      <div class="col s6 offset-s3 l6 offset-l3">
    <div class="head card-panel">
      <div class="header center-align"><h5 class="numPlate">Database Data</h5></div>
    </div></div></div></div></div>
</div>
```

**Update**

I am getting the data from database and its showing up in console.log but its not showing up on web page. For designing,I am using Materializecss.

I have two pages,from one I am inputting a number to search in database and then displaying it on another page if its valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To render some Cloud Firestore data in HTML:

```
// To select the element class details
const dat = document.querySelector(".details");


function renderHTML(doc){
 // TODO: do something with the data 

 // To create elements (such as list or span) 
 let list = document.createElement('li');
 let name = document.createElement('span');

 // To set attributes to elements 
 list.setAttribute('id', doc.id);
 name.textContent = doc.data().name;

 // To append element to the list 
 list.appendChild(name);

 // To append the the list to querySelector
 dat.appendChild(list);
}


db.collection("details").where('plate', '==', num).get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.empty) {
      console.log('No matching documents.');
      return;
    }  
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
      renderHTML(doc);
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
  });
```

More information can be found on the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection)

Comment: Thanks!! this helped me to get specific doc. Can you help me with this .innerhtml representation of data in that function? Problem is it isn't showing up the data just loading blank but specific doc size. I tried creating element but it seems not working. **Thanks for this help though**.

Comment: Similarly to `.textContent`, which uses straight text `String` and does not parse into HTML, you can use `.innerHTML` to insert a text, such as `var dat = document.createElement("P");   dat.innerHTML = "This is a paragraph.";` . More HTML info can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp).

Comment: Sir! **Thanks for helping**. I am still not getting the output though,please recheck the question as I have updated and edited the codes too.

Comment: Glad to hear that you're querying your data correctly. Are you receiving the input from the form as expected? Is the issue solely when displaying the data? If so, you may want to try `plano.textContent = doc.data().plate` and make sure that you are appending this to the correct element. Note that this is a different question now and may warrant a new question in the forum.